# reset variable after each use

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable `$hold` that I use often to hold an array from a database.

I normally just assign the result array to `$hold` and then look inside `$hold` for the array.

Now, normally this will overwrite `$hold` and if there are no results it will just be an empty array.

But lately I've been wondering if I should be manually setting `$hold = ""` or `$hold = NULL` before using the database each time, just in case.

Does anybody have any advice on this?

Comment: Its not a bad idea to reset the value. You can set it to what you like but if you set it to null it would make sense seeings as the value you will be an array not a string. You could even do empty array if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to "empty" a variable before use **unless** it's a reference, in which case you need to unset() it first, but I doubt you are using references. They look like this:

```
$a = &$b;
```

In general every time you "assign" in PHP everything which was there before is replaced, so you can safely do:

```
$hold = database_query(...);
```

Without too much worries. This is different from free'ing the resources held in variables, if a variable contains a file descriptor or a cached database result you need to explicitly call fclose() or mysql_free_result() (just to name a couple of examples).